# Saddled with a server with millions of files in a single directory

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We run several servers that people scan documents to daily, to the tune of about 250,000 per year. The documents rang in size from 10k to 125 megs each. The vender that built the system did not include a mechanism to put the files in a sub folders. So we now have a couple servers with 1-2 million documents stored on them. Getting into these folders is next to impossible and recently I had to resize 50,000 documents and it took over a week to get them identified, copied to another server and put back and then verified that all of them were put back. I found that explorer would not actually display all the files, and I had to use Robocopy to get them copied around.

So the Questions:
1. How in the world are others dealing with these senerios? Other than yelling at the vender.
2. Is there a way to view this many files in a windows explorer type aplication?

Comment: Yell at the vendor is a totally acceptable solution if you ask me.

Comment: Got to agree. Yell at them. This is so basic a design error that I find it hard to believe it ever went through any type of control. The fix is easy enough for them. Filename kjh23423l3242l3k4j234234.tif is moved to kjh/234/23l/324/2l3/k4j/234/234/kjh23423l3242l3k4j234234.tif, they can even release a version which first looks in the root and, if it doesn't find it, looks in kjh/234/23l/324/2l3/k4j/234/234/, which will give clients a chance to move the files to sub directories. Its a bad design in any case. They should have something more intelligent built into the logic.

Comment: Agreed, but they dont have a solution. The records system cost over $250,000 and this is what they gave us. We are in the process of writing an application that can deal with the sheer size of this mess. We are trying to intercept the ftp requests and route to sub folders.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to see them all at once?

Make a simple script which would scan the folder for all files older than (based on your load let's say) 72 hours and move them into `.\<YEAR>\<MONTH>\<DAY>` subfolder creating folders as needed. Optionally you could create an `ALLFILES` subfolder and put symlinks to the moved files into that subfolder.

Then schedule it to run every hour.

Comment: The only need I have for seeing them is when one gets corrupted and I have to replace it from backup. Currently I have to recover the whole folder. Currently that is a 6+ hour task with Apasure. Or the upcoming project to relocate them to a new server. They are all medical records so it is impossible to put them in seperate folders. They all have to be visable when a doc needs them. The vender did try to split them up for another client and in the end the recovered the server to what it was originally. So until they fix it, I guess Im stuck. I have been experimenting with an smb share to linux

Comment: They are currently dished out via filezilla. Yea thats my first choice. This in the app is fast enough, but no other ftp client I have found will even connect to it.

Comment: please tell how exactly do doctors "look" for the files? what are they looking for? do you have some specific naming scheme? do you have let's say patient's ID included in the file name?

Comment: The files are named with a random 25 didgit alpha-numeric name. The application will say "Chest x-ray 12-12-12) the ftp name will be kjh23423l3242l3k4j234234.tif. The user never see's behind the application.